# Accessing a JS Function in IE via iframe.contentWindow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I will do my best to keep this simple. The following code works fine in IE10:

```
if (!document.getElementById(frames[i][j].toString()).contentWindow.MyFunc()) {
        alert("Failed");
        return false;
    }
```

However, in IE8, it fails because "Object doesn't support this property or method" on MyFunc()
It DOES, however, find the contentWindow.

Some potentially useful info:
'frames' is a 2D array of iframe objects.
This code exist in the parent.
MyFunc() is defined in the child iframe.

Essentially, my question boils down to:

```
document.getElementById(frames[i][j].toString()).contentWindow.*whatgoeshere?*
```

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921387/accessing-a-javascript-function-in-a-nested-iframe-in-ie) post, but it didn't prove to help much.
This isn't a case of the iframe not being known (example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341926/calling-a-function-inside-an-iframe-from-outside-the-iframe-in-ie8) post), since the code fires long after the document is ready.
While the error is different (Access Denied), I'm wondering if I will need to do something more complex like what I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002168/iframe-contentwindow-throws-access-denied-error-after-shortening-document-domain) post.

Comment: Is both your content, and the content in the iframes on the same domain?

Comment: you should log the contents of whatever.contentWindow in IE and see if it's what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chris and Arnar for their time and energies spent on this. Turns out it was entirely my fault. Today as I was looking at MyFunc(), I noticed that it was dependent on the jQuery validationEngine:

```
 function MyFunc()() {
    if (!$('#form1').validationEngine('validate')) { return false; }
    $("#btn").click();
    return true;
  }
```

I then noticed that the version of the validationEngine js library was newer on my machine, then the one on my test server...silly me, I hadn't deployed an update I had made to the validationEngine...doh!

For anyone reading this after the fact: 
Check the dependencies of any libraries you might be using (ESPECIALLY in the child function)!